# Need to create some sort of drag and drop datagridview in Visual Studio (preferably C#) to reorder database records

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop

I've got a database that has 183 records.  They each have a field called schedule order which determines their order.  Right now, in order to change the order, I have to open up squirrel and change their values manually.  Is there any way to make some sort of control using visual studio that will let me drag and drop records vertically to change their order, writing the changes to the oracle database as we go?

Comment: Have a look a the `ReOrderListBox` from the [**WPF Bag Of Tricks**](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can reorder rows in a `DataGridView` by drag and drop. Both databound and free DGVs are discussed [here at the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/320c4536-9b32-4a9c-9bfb-567f3a2da15b/drag-drop-reorder-of-row?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

It involves either removing and reinserting rows in the `DataGridView` or in the `DataSet` it is bound to.

When you are happy with the new order you can update the `schedule` fields and then write the rows back to the DBMS.

Comment: Oh wow.  I honestly had no idea that you could do that with DataGridView.  I don't know how I didn't know that... right now I'm having trouble even getting data in the field, so I'll have to mess with that more later.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) 
          RE-ARANGE;
       else
          RE-ARANGE
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Sorry, I've never used DragEnter before.  It seems like it involves dragging things into text boxes

Comment: this function will fire on dragenter event of your list or any other controller

Comment: fetch your items list, sort and re assign it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at products like [Telerik Rad Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx).

Comment: Wow, that looks amazing.  However, my company is not willing to pay for outside packages for this sort of thing.  Wow, that's super cool though.